# symfony environment config files

Tags: symfony

I use fosrestBundle with monolog logger to create a custom log.
I added this conf in config_dev.yml :

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:         fingers_crossed
            action_level: error
            handler:      nested
        nested:
            type:  stream
            path:  "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: debug
        console:
            type:  console
        myCustomLog:
            type:   stream
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/myCustomLog%kernel.environment%.log"
            channels: [myCustomLog]
```

So i did the same in my other environments config files (config_prod.yml, config_qualif.yml ...)

The problem is that may config_prod or config_qualif are not used.

I had this error :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Exception\\ServiceNotFoundException: You have requested a non-existent service "monolog.logger.myCustomLog". in /var/www/myWebSite/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:816\nStack trace:\n#0
```

I moved my monolog conf in the config.yml file and it works in all environments but this is not a good solution.

Can you help me to understand how to correctly use environments config file, because i am not sure what i did is good ? And i am not sure fosrestbundle uses the right environments config file.

My apache conf looks like this for prod environment:

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/myWebSite/web
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex app.php
</IfModule>

<Directory /var/www/myWebSite/web>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        Options +FollowSymlinks
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

for qualif environment, the rewrite rules is :

```
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app_qualif.php [QSA,L]
```

And in app.php i have this line :

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
```

And in app_qualif.php i have this line :

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('qualif', false);
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i solved the problem.

Config files works fine.

The problem came from the command line system. When i called a command i was using this syntax :

```
php app/console app:my-command
```

But using this, symfony doesn't know the environment config to use.
Now i launch my commands with this syntax :

```
php app/console --env=prod app:my-command
```

Answer (score 0):

You set your custom category channel for monolog. You should register a service to handle it. 
You have two solution :

1) create your own service and tag it as a monolog channel handler as explain here : 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/dic_tags.html#dic-tags-monolog

2) Since monolog 2.4 you can register directly your new channel to monolog in config.yml :

```
monolog:
    channels: ["myCustomLog"]
    handlers:
        main:
            type:         fingers_crossed
            action_level: error
            handler:      nested
        nested:
            type:  stream
            path:  "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: debug
        console:
            type:  console
        myCustomLog:
            type:   stream
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/myCustomLog%kernel.environment%.log"
            channels: [myCustomLog]
```

Monolog will create automaticaly the service *monolog.looger.mycustomlog*

Comment: This doesn't  answer the real question : Why config_prod or config_qualif are not used ? your solution works but if i want a different level depending on the environment, i can't do it